# Gulp sass not compiling properly

Tags: gulp, gulp-sass, node-sass

So whats happening is when I edit a scss file and save, gulp task runs with no errors but excludes that files content in my main default.css.

I switch to another scss file, edit that and THAT one is now exluded but the previous gets compiled.

```
gulpfile.js

var gulp = require('gulp'); 
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task('scss', function () {
    return gulp.src('assets/resources/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/css/'));
});

gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch('assets/resources/**/*.scss', ['scss']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['scss', 'watch']);
```

No idea whats going on and not even sure if this is the right place to post this but im at my wits end.

Should also note that doing a normal sass watch from the command line works fine, no issues there.

Gulp 3.9.1
Gulp-sass 4.0.1
Node-sass 4.9.0

File structure if it helps

```
assets/css/default.css 
assets/resources/default.scss 
assets/resources/base/<scss files> 
assets/resources/modules/<scss files>
```

Comment: yeah sorry, that was just a typo trying to post this from mobile.  I'll fix it

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was with gulp-sass.

Uninstalled it then installed gulp-ruby-sass, tweaked task based on the help file and it's working perfectly now